# Injecting a dependency via a maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a system that accepts plugins to let users add functionality to a management system. The plugin is basically just a zip file with in a certain format (ie file x in this dir, y in that dir). Currently I use the maven-assembly-plugin plugin to make the zip.

The problem is that it is awkward to keep all my plugins in sync and to let others make a plugin since they need the correct assembly.xml

Therefore I've been trying to make a custom packaging type so developers can make a plugin like this:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>plugin</packaging> //not a standard type
```

This is mostly working but the ugly thing now is that each plugin always depends on certain APIs in the core system. Therefore they all basically have the same dependencies.

**Is it possible for a mojo to inject dependencies into a user of the mojo?** This seems to say it can't:
http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/How-to-inject-dependencies-from-a-mojo-td83025.html

Comment: Have you read the answer in the thread you've mentioned?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, but that was 5+ years ago. Who knows what happened since then.

Comment: I came across a pretty obvious and simple solution. I make a "pom" project that contains the dependencies, and ask that the developer includes that pom as a dependency. That solves my issue nicely since i can centralize the dependencies in one place and each "plugin" can transitively get to the core api dependencies if they want. Easy Peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> I came across a pretty obvious and simple solution. I make a "pom"
>   project that contains the dependencies, and ask that the developer
>   includes that pom as a dependency. That solves my issue nicely since i
>   can centralize the dependencies in one place and each "plugin" can
>   transitively get to the core api dependencies if they want. Easy
>   Peasy. –  mlathe Mar 27 '13 at 22:12

Comment: I am trying to do the same. One question: When you say "and ask that the developer includes that pom as a dependency", where should the POM be included as dependency? (1) in the POM of the plugin, or (2) in the POM that is consuming the plugin?