# Adding dependency via calling Maven plugin mojo

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-dependency

I have multiple POMs that inherit a dependency via their parent. The dependency is not to a maven plugin, but another project that I have created:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.name.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>id-of-my-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Now I want to remove this from the parent POM file and instead have the children POMs use a custom maven plugin for the same functionality. In that custom maven plugin (which I will create), I want to call/add above dependency. I have tried the following code in a Mojo of the new maven-plugin, but it is not adding the dependency (and gives compilation error):

```
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        try {

            // adding a dependency
            Dependency dep = new Dependency();
            dep.setArtifactId("id-of-my-artifact");
            dep.setGroupId("com.my.name.group");
            dep.setScope("compile");
            dep.setVersion("2.3.0-SNAPSHOT");

            List<Dependency> lst = new ArrayList<Dependency>();
            lst.add(dep);
            project.setDependencies(lst);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            getLog().info(String.format("Exception %s: ", ex));
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Exception has occurred" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

I looked at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647846/injecting-a-dependency-via-a-maven-plugin) and the link provided in that. From the external link, it seems that it is not possible. But in that question, OP seems to have figured it out and provided a short answer, but I cannot understand the answer. Could someone please help me out? I am new to Maven.

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are trying to implement? Maybe I misunderstand a thing but I don't understand the intention you have explained? Can describe what kind of problem you would like to solve with your plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise when I don't want to have any kind of parent for all the different POMs I have but still want to add a dependency in all of them without explicitly mentioning it in their POMs, i.e. via a maven-plugin. I know having a single parent for all of them and adding the dependency in the parent would be the best approach, but I want to do this without having parent POM. I am just asking: is it possible?

Comment: So you would like to move the dependencies into a plugin instead of giving it explicitly in the pom file which I don't find a good idea. Apart from that I have my doubts, cause the pom files are read at the beginning before a plugin is started or a life cycle is running. So If you really would like to go this path I would suggest to take a look how to implement an extension instead...